# Passing a file with argv Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I'm new with ubuntu, and my code in c++ is like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
  //commands
}
```

The code is working perfectly in Windows, but now I'm trying to run it on ubuntu, but the command line:

```
g++ -Wall  code.cpp file.txt
```

returns the error "file format not recognized; treating as linker script"

What can I do to run the code??

Comment: First compile it: `gcc -Wall code.cpp -o code`. Then run it: `./code file.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The g++ is to compile the file, not to execute. So you do not need to pass the file.txt with g++. In your provided command line, the g++ is actually trying to compile the file.txt as a c++ code. You need to provide the file when you will be executing the code. So you will need two command line as follows:

```
g++ -Wall code.cpp
./a file.txt
```

For more details about g++ command for ubuntu, you can visit [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61408/what-is-a-command-to-compile-and-run-c-programs)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer; however, I tried to do what you taught me, but the followig error appeared:                                                                                     file or directory not found, but when I do ls in the directory, it shows the file I used as input. Do you have any idea of why this happened??

Comment: ./a file.txt
bash: ./a: File or directory not found

Comment: @donut: It's `./a.out`. Or just give the output file a name of your own choosing.

Comment: Thank you, good sir, you can't imagine how much you helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing: compilation, linking and execution of your program.

1. Compile your code in objects files
2. Link your object code files into one executable program `g++ -o myProgram thing.cpp code.cpp` (to do both steps at once)
3. Give the execution permission to your executable program `chmod u+x myProgram`
4. Execute your program and pass to it the required arguments. `./myProgram file.txt`

[The C++ compilation process](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/compile.html)

[Compiling C++ programs with g++](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/howto/g++compiling.txt)